# kafka + how to revert topic deletion

Tags: linux, hadoop, kafka

just in case we delete the wrong topic as

```
 /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper hdpmaster01:2181 --delete --topic gtom.poli.pri.proc
```

Topic gtom.poli.pri.procis already marked for deletion
and now we want to revert it

what are the steps to revert topic deletion?

```
 all folders topics as the following are still exists under /var/kafka/kafka-logs

 gtom.poli.pri.procis-23

 gtom.poli.pri.procis-45

 gtom.poli.pri.procis-34
```

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar 3-4 years ago. Binary files in those directories are easily readable, so we copied those directories to another location, written some simple code that reads data and delimiters off binaries, recreated a topic and fed it with output from that simple code ( even bash, `strings` will do the job ).
In our situation disk corruption was the problem, so not all the data has been recovered, most of it.